# Vaadin CropField addon selected image

Tags: vaadin, crop, add-on

The purpose of CropField is to get only selected part of the image. Which method does that? getImageResource() returns the whole image.

The second question is - is it possible to set a cropfield with a predetermined selected area? I've set minimal and maximal values of width and height to the same number so that selection area is always the same. However, user have to click on the cropfield in order to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used this addon.

> The purpose of CropField is to get only selected part of the image

Actually, I think this statement is wrong; according to the description of the addon it

> shows a single image and overlays it with capabilities to select, transform and move a cropping area within it.

i.e. it allows you to manipulate a selection area : it does not actually perform the cropping itself. I guess this could be done using serverside java (or an external tool).

For what it's worth, I agree that the name of the addon suggests that it does do the cropping itself.

As for setting a selection area, the javadoc of the CropField addon shows how to do this `setValue(VCropSelection value)`

```
/**
 * Vaadin component that shows an image with an overlayed cropping
 * functionality. The current selection can be set and get via
 * setValue()/getValue() of {@link AbstractField}. The type of that value has to
 * be {@link VCropSelection}. Usually, the selection will not be changed to a
 * <i>null</i> value. Instead, it will be an empty selection (check with
 * {@link VCropSelection#isEmpty()}).
 * 
 * @author Eric Seckler
 */
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, as for the first question - you were right, it allows to get the coordinates and the original image - that's all I need